# How to convert a binary in string format to a real binary object in Python?

Tags: python

Is there an existing library that can directly convert a binary in string format to a real binary object in Python?

For example, how to convert `'1100'` (string) to `'0b1100'` (byte)?

Comment: `int('1100', 2)`

Comment: int('1100', 2) returns an Integer, NOT byte.

Comment: `0b1100` would also be an integer. See the duplicate how to progress from there.